# How do I make background image in CSS slide into a corner infinitely?

Tags: css, animation, background-image, web-frontend

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.scrolling-image-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    
  }


.scrolling-image {
    background: url("Pictures/z6c3UquP.png") repeat-x;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    width: 1000%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    animation: slide 1200s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    100% {
        transform: translate3d(-90%, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Right now I have this and it works for sliding the background image to the left and it loops infinitely. How can I do this same thing but to change direction so it is going into upper right corner for instance?

Comment: `transform: translate3d(-90%, -90%, 0)` ?

Comment: That doesn't work :/